# Rails Polymorphic associations without nesting forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am still new to rails and I am trying to figure out how to implement a polymorphic association without using a nested route or form. I tried searching but everything seemed to be about nesting forms or adding comments, which is not what I am trying to do.

Here are my models

**Article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :articable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, as: :articable
end
```

**People.rb**

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, as: :articable
end
```

I want to implement a 'New Article' link from a Organization or People show page and have the correct `article_id` and `article_type` entered.  What would the correct syntax be to generate this link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes:

```
resource :people do
  resource :articles
end

resource :organizations do
  resource :articles
end
```

ArticlesController:

```
def create
  article = Article.new(params[:article])
  if params[:people_id]
    people = People.find(params[:people_id])
    people.articles << article 
  else
    organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    organization.articles << article 
  end
  article.save  
end
```

Organizations view:

```
link_to new_organization_article_path(@organization)...
```

Comment: This is starting to make more sense now, thanks.  I used your code, but I am now getting a `dynamic constant assignment` error on the `Organization = Organization .find(params[:organization_id])` line.  Any ideas on that one?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yes, i mistakenly assigned the constant instead of the variable. check the last edit. Regardless, i didn't test this code, it was meant to serve as a guideline to the final solution.